# Custom object create/edit through force.com sites - no fields visible

Tags: force.com-sites

I have a VF page that allows someone to create a record in a custom object 'Co_op_Fund__c'.  When the page is viewed through the site, I see the labels and Save button but none of the fields are visible/editable.  I made sure the guest site profile has all CRUD, even View/Modify All; Org wide security is public r/w on the object and I ran through FLS for all fields to be editable.  Still for some reason I can't get the field values to display.

I feel like I'm missing some basic step but in all the years I've been combining VF with sites I haven't been stuck like this before.
Any thoughts on where else to look?

```
<apex:page controller="PartnerCoopFundController" >

<apex:form id="form">        

                   <!-- error text section -->
                   {!pgErrors}
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!validContact}">

                        <table class="primary-acc-table edit-user-table" style="border: 0;">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="licenseTable">
                                    <div class="label">Activity Name</div> 
                                    <div class="content"><apex:inputField value="{!coop.Activity_Name__c}" styleClass="inputFieldsCustom" required="true"/></div>
                                </td> 
                                <td class="licenseTable"> 
                                    <div class="label">Activity Type</div> 
                                    <div class="content"><apex:inputField value="{!coop.Activity_Type__c}" styleClass="inputFieldsCustom" required="true"/></div>  
                                </td>
                            </tr>
... more rows of inputFields
                                <tr> <td rows="2"> <apex:commandButton action="{!saveRequest}" value="Save"  styleclass="cccBtn"  /></td></tr>                                                                                                                                                                                            
                        </table>
                </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:form>
```

[image]

Comment: double check FLS for guest user profile .I can only think of FLS in your case

Comment: Deployment Status!  I was using an object my coworker created in sandbox and it was set to 'In Development'.  Testing as an admin worked fine since admins can see objects in development but I guess the site guest user can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was the object's Deployment Status set to 'In Development'.  Once it was set to 'Deployed' the sites page worked as expected.

Comment: Please mark your answer as answered :)